# How to store a PropertyGroup in addon_prefs?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

i made some research about propertygroups. it could be really useful if the data of thoses propertygroups are saved within my addon pref and not reset between each blender session. How am i supposed to do that ?

i did an addon example using propertygroups.

```
# "Scatter" Add-on
# Copyright (C) 2019 Dorian Borremans aka BD3D
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
# <pep8 compliant>
bl_info = {
    "name" : "PropertyGroup [BD3D]", 
    "author" : "BD3D",   
    "description" : "The scattering tool of 2.8",
    "blender" : (2, 80, 0),
    "location" : "Operator",
    "warning" : "",
    "category" : "Generic"
}
import bpy
import bmesh
import random
from bpy.types import Menu, Panel, Operator, PropertyGroup
import webbrowser
from bpy.types import Operator, AddonPreferences, PropertyGroup
from bpy.props import StringProperty, IntProperty, BoolProperty, FloatProperty, EnumProperty, PointerProperty
import rna_keymap_ui
context = bpy.context


######################################################################################
######################################################################################
# # # # # # # # # # # #          ADDON PREF STORAGE            # # # # # # # # # # # # 
######################################################################################
######################################################################################
class ScatterPref(AddonPreferences):
    bl_idname = __name__
    addon_prefs = context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences

    scatter_01_name                = StringProperty(name="Custom slot name",subtype='NONE',default="Custom01")



######################################################################################
######################################################################################
# # # # # # # # # # # #            ADDON PREF UI               # # # # # # # # # # # #
######################################################################################
######################################################################################
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        full= "................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................"
        addon_prefs = context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences

        bigbox = layout.box().box()
        col=layout.column()

        col.prop(self,"scatter_01_name")

        self.layout.prop(bpy.context.scene.sample_vars, 'variable1')
        self.layout.prop(bpy.context.scene.sample_vars, 'variable2')
        self.layout.prop(bpy.context.scene.sample_vars, 'variable3')




class SampleVariables(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    variable1 = bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name="per square emission",
        description="Sample variable 1",
        default=100
    )
    variable2 = bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name="emission",
        description="Sample variable 2",
        default=5555
    )
    variable3 = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name="is per square",
        description="Sample variable 3",
        default=True
    )


######################################################################################
######################################################################################
# # # # # # # # # # # #        SCATTER OPERATOR                # # # # # # # # # # # # 
######################################################################################
######################################################################################
class Scatter_OT_Slots_Custom(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "scatter.custom_slot_operator"
    bl_label = "Custom Scattering Operator"
    bl_description = ""

    def execute(self, context):
        context = bpy.context
        addon_prefs = context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences
        scene = context.scene
        A = context.object

        bm = bmesh.new() #four area calculation lines from stack exchange
        bm.from_mesh(A.data) 
        squarearea = sum(f.calc_area() for f in bm.faces)
        bm.free()

        A.select_set(state=False)
        for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
            particlename = addon_prefs.scatter_01_name

            pref = "SCATTER: ["+particlename+"] v."
            i = 1
            name = "%s%d" % (pref, i)
            while A.modifiers.get(name):    
                i += 1
                name = "%s%d" % (pref, i)
            ### ### add particle system + rename and add selection in new coll
            m = A.modifiers.new(name, type='PARTICLE_SYSTEM')

            ps = m.particle_system
            ps.name = name
            ps.settings.name = name
            ps.settings.type = 'HAIR'

            ps.settings.render_type = 'OBJECT'
            ps.settings.instance_object = bpy.data.objects[ob.name]
            ps.settings.hair_length = 4

            print(bpy.context.scene.sample_vars.variable1)
            print(bpy.context.scene.sample_vars.variable2)
            print(bpy.context.scene.sample_vars.variable3)

            #if SampleVariables.variable3 == True:
            #    ps.settings.count = SampleVariables.variable1 * squarearea
            #else:
            #    ps.settings.count = SampleVariables.variable2

        A.select_set(state=True)

        return {'FINISHED'}

######################################################################################
######################################################################################
# # # # # # # # # # # #            N MENU                      # # # # # # # # # # # # 
######################################################################################
######################################################################################


class Scatter_PT_ScatteringPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "Scatter_PT_ScatteringPanel"
    bl_label = "Scatter !"
    bl_category = "Scatter"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_context = "objectmode"  

    def draw(self, context):


        addon_prefs = bpy.context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences
        layout = self.layout

        layout.prop(bpy.context.scene.sample_vars, 'variable1')
        layout.prop(bpy.context.scene.sample_vars, 'variable2')
        layout.prop(bpy.context.scene.sample_vars, 'variable3')

        box=layout.box()
        bigbutton = box.column()
        bigbutton.scale_y=2
        bigbutton.operator(Scatter_OT_Slots_Custom.bl_idname, text="SCATTER",  icon='PLAY')


######################################################################################
######################################################################################
# # # # # # # # # # # #                 REG                    # # # # # # # # # # # # 
######################################################################################
######################################################################################

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ScatterPref)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Scatter_PT_ScatteringPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Scatter_OT_Slots_Custom)

    bpy.utils.register_class(SampleVariables)
    bpy.types.Scene.sample_vars = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=SampleVariables)


def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Scene.sample_vars
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SampleVariables)

    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ScatterPref)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Scatter_PT_ScatteringPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Scatter_OT_Slots_Custom)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

do i need to use pointerPref ? How to use it ?

```
class ScatterPref(AddonPreferences):
    bl_idname = __name__
    addon_prefs = context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences


    addon_prefs.sample_vars = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=SampleVariables)
```

Comment: I don't really get *why*? I think you can either use a `CollectionProperty` or a `PointerProperty` to solve your issue, [here](https://gist.github.com/p2or/d6dfd47366b2f14816f57d2067dcb6a9) is an example. Notice that there are a few bad references in your script: Within an operator you already have *context* so you can replace `bpy.context.scene.sample_*` with `context.scene.sample_*`. Also as of 2.8x we have to use annotations `:` for property assignments like `variable1 = bpy.props.IntProperty(...`.

Comment: @p2or thanks, because of your example i know that i need to ```bpy.context.scene.sample_vars.variable1``` instead of  just ```sample_vars.variable1``` ! But i don't see how it can help with addon_prefs ? there's none in this example ? am i missing something ? i'm quite new to python and blender api.

Comment: That's the wrong way around :) In other words: You already have `context` (passed via operator methods like `execute`, `draw`, `invoke` etc.) so you don't have to write `bpy.context.scene...*` rather start with `context.scene...*`... The example provided might help on how to deal with a `CollectionProperty` to *manage* your addon preferences because this type (as the name suggests) allows to bundle/combine *multiple other properties* of any type per item/entry. Items of the `PropertyGroup` will be saved per scene/session/blend anyway, so you don't have to worry about that.